# Related Tags - How is this list determined?

Tags: support, tagging

On the right side of the page, when you are looking at questions, there's a list of related tags. What determines that a tag is related? It doesn't seem to be a compilation of the tags for the visible questions, so what is it?

ps I've had a really hard time tagging questions here on meta, so please retag as appropriate.

Comment: Do you mean the related questions? I have not seen a "related tags" anywhere.

Comment: Start at the main page - click on questions - look on the right side margin - it's there. I don't know how to insert a screenshot here.

Comment: Aha! I never noticed that.

Answer (score 2):

It's determined by looking at all of the questions in the current list and totaling their tag counts.

If you scan down the list of "related tags" and at the same time scan down the list of questions, you'll see that they basically match.

Normally, your view would consist of questions all containing a specific tag, so "related tags" tells you which tags are shared most often (sort of a "customers who bought this product also bought..." feature).  If you just go to the questions page, you're not looking at any specific tag, so the "related tags" is telling you the tags belonging to the newest questions (or top-voted questions, or whatever you're looking at).